# Dax Measure - Value table compare value

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerpivot, ssas-tabular

I have a table FactSales

And tried but didn’t get ant satisfactory result.

Id like to calculate old results and compare to my actual one and see how many customers whose bought product B before (before 90 days) didn’t buy the same product in last 3 months according to the date filter

I tried this:

> ```
> Customers inactive =
>
> VAR Daysbefore90: Max(DimDate[date]) -90
>
> > RETURN CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT(FSales[CustomerKey]); DimProduct[Product] = “A”; FILTER( ALL ( DimDate[Date] );
> ```
>
> DimDate[Date] < DaysBefore90 ); NOT(CONTAINS( FILTER(FSales;
>   RELATED(DimDate[Date]) >= Daysbefore90 && DimDate[Date]) <=
>   MAX(Daysbefore90): RELATED(DimProduct[Product])  = “A”) ;
>   FSales[CustomerKey]; FSales[CustomerKey] ) ) )

Comment: Please clean up your code. I can't make sense out of it the way it's currently showing up.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all customer who purchased item 'B' in the last 90 Days:

```
Customers Who Bought Product B 90 Days Ago :=
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'FSale'[CustomerKey] ),
    ALL ( 'DimDate'[Date] ),
    KEEPFILTERS (
        DATESINPERIOD ( 'DimDate'[Date], MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] ), -90, DAY )
    ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( DimProduct[Product] = "B" )
)
```

Your question is a little hard to read, so maybe update it and we can go from there.